# zsh tail function not displaying correct file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

If I list the directory contents in most recent modified order and get the most recent file with:

`print dir/*(om[1])`

I get the most recently modified file. However, if I just want the file name by using the :t modifier like:

`print dir/*(om[1]:t)`

it returns the oldest modified file's file name. My understanding was that the modifier :t is the last action on the returned results and, therefore, it should return the file name of the most recently modified file.
Does anyone know why I am getting this unexpected result and how to fix it?

Many Thanks

Paul

Comment: This behavior seems to be the case with all modifiers (`a`, `e`, `l`, etc.) not just `t`. The ordering seems to be consistent between different modifiers, but differs when there is a path component in the pattern: `print *(om)` produces a list ordered by date as expected as does `print ./*(om)`. `print *(om:t)*` seems to be arbitrarily ordered, `print ./*(om:t)` seems to alphabetical. most curiously, with `print */*(om:t)` the returned list is ordered first by the modification date of the first matched glob and but then arbitrarily by the second glob. I suspect that this may be a bug in `zsh`.

Comment: I posted a bug report to zsh-workers@zsh.org.